# ASPX VSFTPD C# Help createing users

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vsftpd

Is it possable to create a new user on a vsftpd server using the user and password from the authentication pages from MS's LOGIN methods? I also don't want to have to restart the vsftpd for them to gain access.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to create the users on your vsftpd server from within the asp.net app as well? Or you are just asking whether you can use the same username/password to create new users on your vsftpd server in general? Is the vsftpd server a Linux or a Windows Box? Is your asp .net app hosted on Windows or Linux (using mono)?

Comment: When someone registers on my website using the MS authentication screens which are running on a ISP, at the same time i would like to create a user and home dir on my FTP server running in my office.  So if they change passwords and suck they would stay in sync and they wouldn't have to login twice.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't do this automatically from within the ASP.NET application hosted at your ISP.

You could, depending on the authentication mechanism used in your asp.net app, have a separate program/job to transfer over the user credentials to your local vsftpd server and sync the user accounts.